# Codeigniter pagination showing duplicate records with page query string

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

i have created pagination with codeigniter 3.
On every page i am getting same results:
my final url seems like: http://localhost/shoping/products/mobile-phones?cid=3&page=2

Controller file:

```
public function category(){
    $category_id = $this->input->get('cid', TRUE);
    $slug = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $sortby = $this->input->get('sort', TRUE);
    $sorttype= 'ASC';
    $limit = 10;
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'products/'.$slug.'?cid='.$category_id;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Product_model->category_product_count($category_id);
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
    //      $config["uri_segment"] = 3;         
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '«';
    $config['next_link'] = '»';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li><a class="current">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] = round($choice);
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    if($this->uri->segment(2) > 0){
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(2) + 0)*$config['per_page'] - $config['per_page'];
    }
    else{
        $page = $this->uri->segment(2);
    }
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    if($data["links"]!= '') {
        $data['pagermessage'] = 'Showing '.((($this->pagination->cur_page-1)*$this->pagination->per_page)+1).' to '.($this->pagination->cur_page*$this->pagination->per_page).' of '.$config['total_rows'];
    } 
    if($this->input->get('sort')=='pricelow'){
        $sortby = 'price';
        $sorttype= 'ASC';
    }   
    elseif($this->input->get('sort')=='pricehigh'){
        $sortby = 'price';
        $sorttype= 'DESC';
    }
    elseif($this->input->get('sort')=='new'){
        $sortby = 'updated_on';
        $sorttype= 'DESC';
    }
    elseif($this->input->get('sort')=='popularity'){
        $sortby = 'price';
        $sorttype= 'DESC';
    }
    else{
        $sortby = 'title';
        $sorttype= 'ASC';
    }   
    //Get all products
    $data['products_by_category'] = $this->Product_model->get_products_by_category($category_id, $config["per_page"], $page, $sortby, $sorttype);
    //      echo $config['total_rows'];
    // Load View
    $data['main_content'] = 'public/products_category';
    $this->load->view('public/layouts/home_main', $data);
}
```

Model File:

```
public function get_products_by_category($category_id, $limit, $start='', $shortby='', $shorttype=''){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('category_id', $category_id);
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->order_by($shortby, $shorttype);
    $query = $this->db->get('products');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

and view file:

```
<?php foreach($products_by_category as $product): ?>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                                <div class="single-product" style="height:300px;margin-bottom:10px">
                                                    <span class="sale-on">sale</span>
                                                    <div class="product-image">
                                                        <div class="show-img">
                                                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?><?php echo $product->slug.'?sid='.$product->id;?>">
                                                                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/products/<?php echo $product->image;?>" alt="<?php echo $product->title;?>" height="150" width="150">
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="prod-info">
                                                        <h2 class="pro-name">
                                                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?><?php echo $product->slug.'?sid='.$product->id;?>"><?php echo $product->title.$product->id;?></a>
                                                        </h2><br>
                                                        <div class="price-box">
                                                            <div class="price">
                                                                <span><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><?php echo $product->price;?></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="old-price">
                                                                <span><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><?php echo $product->mrp_price;?></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="actions">
                                                            <span class="new-pro-wish">
                                                                <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
                                                            </span>
                                                            <span class="new-pro-compaire">
                                                                <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to compare"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i></a>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$this->uri->segment(2)`, use `$this->input->get('page', TRUE)`.

See [CI_Input::get](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::get) for more information on how you can *get* query string variables.

Comment: Thanks tushar. it was big pain.

Comment: I see you were getting category id correctly `$this->input->get('cid', TRUE)`.