# how to save multiple input fields value in mysql with codeigniter

Tags: php, json, forms, codeigniter, mysqli

I have a form having 6 fields with same nameLike - feature[],

I want to save multiple input fields value into mysql 1 column in JSON format:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>product/save/">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="feature[]" placeholder="fetaure 1">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="feature[]" placeholder="fetaure 2">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="feature[]" placeholder="fetaure 3">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="feature[]" placeholder="fetaure 4">
<?php ?>
```

I have column feature in mysql table, i want to save input field value into feature column as json data. i am using codeigniter 3.

Comment: $data = implode(" ",$this->input->post('feature'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ex for codeignitor

```
function save()
{
  $feature = $this->input->post('feature');
  $json = json_encode($feature);
  $this->Your_model_Name->save($json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to get the **INPUTS** based on the form method. Save the inputs in a variable based on form method post/get.

**POST:**

```
$features=$_POST["feature"];
```

**GET:**

```
$features=$_GET["feature"];
```

`$features` will be a PHP Array and you can use json_encode() to encode the **PHP Array** to **JSON String**. Like this,

```
$features_json=json_encode($features);
```

Now use this variable `$features_json` to save **JSON String** in MySQL Database.

Your **JSON String** after encoding will look like this: http://json-parser.com/67c07feb

Answer (score 0):

### controller (product)

```
function save() {
    $features = $this->input->post('feature');
    $feature_json = json_encode($features);
    //send to model
    $this->load->model('your_model');
    $this->your_model->insert($feature_json);
}
```

### model

```
function insert($feature_json) {
     $data = array(
          'features' => $feature_json
     );
     $this->db->insert($data);
}
```

### update

Add trim and xss clean using form validation

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('feature[]',"Feature", "trim|xss_clean");
```

Comment: is it required to trim the $data?

Comment: You can use trim and xss_clean with faorm validation of codeigniter. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an array, you need a foreach loop. your function must look like this

**Controller**

```
function save()
{
    foreach($this->input->post('feature') as $f)
    {
       $f = trim($f);
       $data = json_encode($f);
       $this->YOUR_MODEL->insert_to_table($data);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
function insert_to_table($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('table_name',$data);
}
```

This way, you post every input you have

hope this helps

Comment: is it required to trim the data?

Comment: Trim the post? I think if you want to remove the whitespaces, which is always needed. I'll add trim

Comment: Thanks for reply. also needed xss_clean?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with the data to secure it, that's just the base. If I helped you you can help me by upvoting my post anyway. Have fun coding!

Comment: sure i will upvote. can you please help me with this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814116/codeigniter-pagination-showing-duplicate-records-with-page-query-string

Comment: @Vikas you didn't yet. hah :D, Anyway I'll take a look at your next question and answer with all I can.